# How to generate an expired key with gpg?

Tags: gnupg, key-generation, expiration-date

For testing purposes, I need a PGP key for a specific uid that has already expired.

Using `gpg --full-generate-key` only gives me the following options:

```
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
```

So the nearest expiration date I can set is tomorrow, which means that I'd have to wait 24 hours before I can perform my tests.

Is there a way to create an expired key other than changing the system date and time?

(I'm looking for a solution on macOS or Linux.)

Comment: Instead of changing the system date you could fake it only for gpg: https://serverfault.com/questions/138325/faking-the-date-for-a-specific-shell-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an expiration timestamp (in UTC) by typing something like “20220623T223000” for June 23rd, 2022, 22:30:00 UTC.

GnuPG will still consider that expiration timestamps in the past are invalid. It will however accept to generate a key that will expire in a few second.